# PHP - SimpleHTMLDom Webscraping

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am trying to scrape a table of a certain page, but I am having trouble to do so. I want to get the columns **name**, **level** and **experience** from the table. The table also has different background colors for each row (zebra pattern or whatever it's called), which makes it harder.

I am using SimpleHTMLDom to do this, and here is my code:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

function scrapeHighscore($world) {
    $html = str_get_html('https://secure.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=highscores&world=' . $world);
    $tables = $html->find('table');
    foreach($tables as $table) {
        $names = $table->find('a');
        foreach($names as $name) {
            return $name . ' - ';
        }

        $levels = $table->find('td[@width="15%"]');
        foreach ($levels as $level) {
            return $level . ' - ';
        }

        $experiences = $table->find('td[@width="20%"]');
        foreach ($experiences as $experience) {
            return $experience . '<br>';
        }
    }
}

echo scrapeHighscore('Antica');

?>
```

An example website I want to scrape is:
https://secure.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=highscores&world=Antica

You see the ID, the Name, the Level and the Experience in that table.
I want to scrape only the name/level/experience, and print it out on my website like this:

```
Meendel 536 2538560931
Drendaric   514 2237710308
Magicalse   509 2180132453
...
King Migoon 446 1460356304
```

How would I go about doing this? So far my script does not return anything. It is just a blank page.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code, at ``return $experience . '<br>;`` you missed a ``'``

Comment: I noticed that and fixed it, but i still dont get anything on my page. It's just all blank. Any clue what I have done wrong and how to fix it? I really can't seem to figure this out and it's been bugging me for a few hours @Rocky

Answer (score 0):

```
function scrapeHighscore($world) {
    $output = '';
    $html = str_get_html('https://secure.tibia.com/community   /?subtopic=highscores&world=' . $world);
    $tables = $html->find('table');
    foreach($tables as $table) {

        $names = $table->find('a');
        foreach($names as $name) {
            $output.= $name . ' - ';
        }

        $levels = $table->find('td[@width="15%"]');
        foreach ($levels as $level) {
            $output.= $level . ' - ';
        }

        $experiences = $table->find('td[@width="20%"]');
        foreach ($experiences as $experience) {
            $output.= $experience . '<br>;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
echo scrapeHighscore('Antica');
```

You returend everything which had the restult that only the first name would be printed.

If you get nothing at all do this:

```
$html = str_get_html('https://secure.tibia.com/community   /?subtopic=highscores&world=' . $world);
echo $html;
```

to see what you get. If that echos nothing aswell you should check how `str_get_html` works and where a problem might be.

Comment: I still do not get anything when I used it. And when I used your test you posted at bottom to see if I got anything, then it worked and it echo'd the whole page. I still don't understand why it won't echo the table items

Comment: Now there is nothing returned at all. Maybe place a `return $output;` at the end of the `scrapeHighscore` function?

Comment: @mhall oh yes. I totaly forgot that in the hurry. Sorry!